# What are the only needed files for custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, custom, development

I've seen a lot of tutorials on how to create a custom module in Magento. But all of them are mostly those helloworld examples.

I'm wondering what files do we actually have to create in order to just create a module that's been reckognized by the system.

What are the only important files that have to exist for the module?
I'm thinking that only confing.xml and namespace_Modulename.xml are needed for a new module and everything else is like extra for that (example showing stuff on the page etc).

Comment: If you only add one file `namespace_Modulename.xml` the system will recon it as a module and will show it on **System > Config > Advanced**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Magento 1 answer

You are right... all you need to get your module loaded are:

- app/etc/modules/My_Module.xml
- app/code/pool/My/Module/etc/config.xml

Answer (score 1):

## Magento 2 answer

For **Magento 2**, the only files needed for a Module are:

- `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/registration.php`
- `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml`

These are their contents:

**`app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/registration.php`**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName;

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_ModuleName', __DIR__);
```

**`app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/registration.php`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

Answer (score -1):

For Magento 2, You will need only these two files for developing a module :

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```